# How to analyze strings

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to take a string of numbers each separated by a space, and turn it into a list. The user inputs the string of numbers by typing a number, then a space, as needed. This goes into "myString." I want to take the string and take just the numbers, and add it to myList. The code I want to create is something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
    {
        //If its not a space, add it to the list
        if (myString[i] != " ")
        {
            myList.Add(prices[i]);
        }
    }
```

The error however says that you cannot use the '!=' operator to the types char, and string. Makes sense, but I am having a hard time finding an alternative. Is there a more efficient way to turn a string of: "1 2 3 4 5" into a List?

This is for the google jams code challenge, as I am just practicing on old questions. The link can be found here:
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p0

Thank you for all the help guys! I'm always amazed at how helpful SO is for High School programmers like me who still really have no clue what they're doing :-)

Comment: `" "` is a string. `' '` is a char

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I'm amazed at my stupidity sometimes. Thank you!

Comment: If you just wanted to add the numbers to the list and ignore spaces then you should check out [String.Split on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You could use `myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' });` to convert the whole string into an array of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Split` method instead

```
var numbers = myString.Split().Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

BTW,in order to represent a `char` constant *single quotes* are used in `C#`. So as already mentioned in the comments, `" "` is a `string` literal that contains a *space* not a `char`.You should use `' '`

Comment: So if I understand you right, do you think an array is easier to use in this situation than a list? I need to do some research on the pros/cons of each.

Comment: @TylerJones if you don't want to add new items then you can use Array, otherwise you can use `List<T>`, btw you can use all LINQ methods with  an Array, there is no difference.also if you have too much numbers to search then you can consider using a HashSet<T> instead, for better and faster lookup

Comment: Alright, it sounds like an array would be the best use for this project then. Thanks @Selman22.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, to fix your error change your line to:

```
if (myString[i] != ' ')  // change to single quotes.
```

Second, there is an easier way:

```
string.Split(new char[] {' '});  // this will return the array you're seeking...
```

Answer (score 2):

`myString[i]` is a `char`, so instead of `" "` you should use `' '` single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to split the string on the spaces, resulting in a list of stirngs representing the numbers.

```
myList = myString.Split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your string on space. You can use LINQ like:

```
List<int> list = myString.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(int.Parse)
                         .ToList();
```

If you want a safer option and replace any invalid entry to `-1` you can use `int.TryParse` like:

```
int temp;
List<int> list = myString.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(r => { return int.TryParse(r, out temp) ? temp : -1; })
    .ToList();
```